# jquery function not working if alert is commented out

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I am running a post function, then after the function is over. I am running another function. Problem is the second function does not work, if I do not have an alert message in the function, it does not run...

jquery function is:

```
function applyeditable(){
    //alert('trying to apply editable class...');

$(".edit_mystatus").editable('/cgi-bin/my_cgi_script.pl', {
event       : 'dblclick',       //or dblclick
data        : " {'A':'Active','C':'Completed','D':'Deleted'}",
type        : 'select',
submit      : 'Ok',
indicator   : '<img src="http://my_website/images/indicator.gif">',
placeholder : 'Double Click to Edit',
tooltip     : 'Double Click to edit...',
style       : 'display: inline',
name        : 'name',
id          : 'id',
callback    : function(value, settings) {
                // console.log(this);
                // console.log('returned value= '+value+' we have to now disable rest of form if Completed or Deleted');
                // console.log(settings);
                }
});
$(".edit_mynotes").editable('/cgi-bin/my_cgi_script.pl', {
    event       : 'dblclick',       //or dblclick
    type        : 'textarea',
    rows        : 10,
    cols        : 100,
    cancel      : 'Cancel',
    submit      : 'Save',
    indicator   : '<img src="http://my_website/images/indicator.gif">',
    placeholder : 'Double Click to enter text',
    tooltip     : 'Double Click to edit...',
    style       : 'display: inline',
    name        : 'name',
    id          : 'id'
});
$(".ajaxfileupload").editable('/cgi-bin/my_cgi_script.pl', {
    type        : 'ajaxupload',
    submit      : 'Upload',
    cancel      : 'Cancel',
    indicator   : '<img src="http://my_website/images/indicator.gif">',
    tooltip     : "Double Click to upload...",
    style       : 'display: inline',
    name        : 'filename',
    id          : 'id'
});

$(".checkclass").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox
    var chkboxval = $this.val();
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        alert('the checkbox was checked val='+chkboxval);
    } else {
        alert('the checkbox was UNchecked val='+chkboxval);
    }
});
}
```

html is:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkclass" value="1_0">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkclass" value="1_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkclass" value="1_2">
```

...

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: It probably works just fine, you're just experiencing what asynchronous means,

Comment: When alert is fired.. it just gives some time to complete the request .. that's the only reason you feel it works when there is an alert

Comment: oh.... means, this code runs even before all the newly added elements are laid out on the webpage? (the function calling this function is adding bunch of new elements to the page and then calling this function to bind events)..... If it is only about delay, how can I add the delay?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function applyeditable has to be called from the innermost 'on success' event of the calling function. that will take care of async nature of things.

for example:

callingfunction(abc){
...
...

```
$.get(data, function(myfile) {
$("#someid").html(myfile);
applyeditable()     //this call runs after above is success (100% execution)
});
```

...
}